# Comment answer mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that people can send comments:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `reference` int(11),
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `answer` int(11)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

if this comment is an answer for another comment `answer` has its id.
I have this select:

```
select id, user, data, ip, answer from comments where reference = ? and answer = 0
```

so I can get all post comments by reference id and skip it if it is an answer.

The problem is, if one comment has answers, how can I select this answers inside its comments in this select? ex:

```
comment 1
answer comment 1 (1)
answer comment 1 (2)
comment 2
comment 3
comment 4
answer comment 4 (1)
answer comment 4 (2)
comment 5
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could

```
SELECT q.id as question_id , q.user as question_user, 
       q.data as question_data, q.ip as question_ip, 
       a.id as answer_id , q.user  as answer_user, 
       a.data  as answer_data, a.ip  as answer_ip  

FROM comments q LEFT JOIN comments a on q.id=a.answer 

WHERE q.reference = ?
```

Then in php you could loop through the results and assemble an array accoding to your needs.